# Integral of birth-death process up to stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, birth-death-process

We are trying to find the average sum of branches on a tree representing a birth-death process, with fixed birth and death parameters.

Let $X_t$ be the number of individuals at time $t\geq 0$, with $X_0=0$. Suppose we stop the process when $X_t=n$. This defines a stopping time $T$, and hence, if $T$ is finite, we have to compute the integral

$$E[\int_{0}^{T}X_t dt]$$

Since the integral goes up to a stopping time, I don't think I can exchange the expectation and the integral. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Note sure if that's helpful, but by [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions), you have
$$\mathbb E\left[\int_{0}^{T}X_t\  dt\right] = \mathbb E\left[\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{t\le T}X_t\ dt \right] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{t\le T}X_t]\ dt  $$